# android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:104)

Tags: android

I'm new to android, and I want to get images from the server and load them in the layout.
But my code only runs until `Log.e("error","115"); the imageView can't initialize.`
This is my code:

```
package com.example.mywaterfallversion2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

private final int NUM_OF_PIC = 30; 
private  LinearLayout linearLayout1 = null;
private  LinearLayout linearLayout2 = null;
private  LinearLayout linearLayout3 = null;
private  View scrollView = null;
public static int USE_LINEAR_INTERVAL = 0;
public static int linearlayoutWidth = 0;
private byte[][] picBytes = new byte[NUM_OF_PIC][];
private int numOfPic = 0;
private int index = 0; 
public static int requestTime = 0;
private PictureArrayOfBytes picArray ;
View view;
ImageView imageView;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
        switch (msg.what) {  
        case 1:   
          try {
            Log.e("error","39");
            addBitmaps();
            Log.e("error","41");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            break;  
        default :
                break;
        }  
    } 
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout1);
    linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout2);
    linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout3);
    linearlayoutWidth =  (int)(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/3);
    Log.e("error","creat: " + String.valueOf(linearlayoutWidth));

    scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    Log.e("error","61");
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new MainActivity());
    Log.e("error","65");
    thread.start();
    Log.e("error","67");
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
            switch (event.getAction()) {  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :  
                    break;  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :  
                    index++;  
                    break;  
                default :  
                    break;  
            }  
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP &&  index > 0) {  
                index = 0;  
                view = ((ScrollView) v).getChildAt(0);  
                if (view.getMeasuredHeight() <= v.getScrollY() + v.getHeight()) {  

                        if (numOfPic >= NUM_OF_PIC){
                            numOfPic = 0;
                            thread.start();
                        }
                }  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  
    });  
    Log.e("error","90");
}



private void addBitmaps() throws Exception{
     Log.e("error","87");


    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIC; i++){
        Log.e("error","110");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picBytes[i], 0, picBytes[i].length);
        Log.e("error","113");
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapZoom.bitmapZoomByWidth(bitmap, linearlayoutWidth); //compressed the image
        Log.e("error","linearlayoutWidth = "+ String.valueOf(linearlayoutWidth));
        **Log.e("error","115");**
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Log.e("error","117");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        Log.e("error","105");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bitmap2.getWidth() + 5, bitmap2.getHeight() + 5);

        Log.e("error","109");
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Log.e("error","111");

        switch (USE_LINEAR_INTERVAL) 
        {
            case 0:
                linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
                numOfPic++;
                break;
            case 1:
                linearLayout2.addView(imageView);
                numOfPic++;
                break;
            case 2:
                linearLayout3.addView(imageView);
                numOfPic++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        USE_LINEAR_INTERVAL++;
        USE_LINEAR_INTERVAL= USE_LINEAR_INTERVAL%3;
    }
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        requestTime++;
        picArray = new PictureArrayOfBytes(requestTime);
        picBytes = picArray.getPicByteArray();
        Message message = new Message();  
        message.what = 1;  
        Log.e("error","153");
        mHandler.sendMessage(message);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The logcat info:

```
06-08 02:11:02.109: E/error(900): linearlayoutWidth = 240

06-08 02:11:02.109: E/error(900): 115    (*the code run here,can't continue* )

06-08 02:11:02.109: W/System.err(900): java.lang.NullPointerException

06-08 02:11:02.130: W/System.err(900):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)

06-08 02:11:02.130: W/System.err(900):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2696)

06-08 02:11:02.130: W/System.err(900):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:104)

06-08 02:11:02.139: W/System.err(900):  at com.example.mywaterfallversion2.MainActivity.addBitmaps(MainActivity.java:117)

06-08 02:11:02.139: W/System.err(900):  at com.example.mywaterfallversion2.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:105)

06-08 02:11:02.139: W/System.err(900):  at com.example.mywaterfallversion2.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:41)

06-08 02:11:02.163: W/System.err(900):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-08 02:11:02.163: W/System.err(900):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something's weird. Why does your activity implement Runnable? `addBitmaps()` seems to only be called from the `onRun()`, how are you getting that `onRun()` to be executed? Activities cannot be instantiated by your code (you *can't* do `new MainActivity()`), you have to let the framework instantiate it. Wherever you're calling the runnable from, the activity is not properly initialized yet and the `context` is null.